# Maximum area of semicircle

Tags: calculus

A rectangle has sides $a$ and $a\sqrt{2}$. How large is the area of the greatest semicircle that can be inscribed in this rectangle?

### **Possible Solution.**

One can, without compromising generality, assume that $a=1$ and later multiply the end result by $a.$ Sketching reveals that the diameter of the semi-circle can not be parallell to any of the sides of the rectangle in order to be maximum. However, letting the round side of the semi-circle be tangent to both sides, we get an illustration looking like this:

[image: Fig 1]

From Figure 1 we have that $0\leq t\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. The semi-circle only lies within the rectangle if and only if $r+r\sin{t}\leq 1$ and $r+r\cos{t}\leq\sqrt{2}.$ These inequalities can also be written as $$  \left\{
    \begin{array}{l}
      r\leq\frac{1}{1+\sin{t}}=f(t)\\
      r\leq\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1+\cos{t}}=g(t)
    \end{array}
  \right.$$
Now we have to choose $r$ and $t$ such that they satisfy the above inequalities and and $r$ is as large as possible. Since $f(t)$ is a decreasing function and $g(t)$ is an increasing function in the given interval, this means that when $f(x)=g(x)$ we obtain the desired value of $t$. Setting up the equation we get $$\sqrt{2}-1+\sqrt{2}\sin{t}=\cos{t}.$$ Squaring and trigonometric identeties yield $$3\sin^2{t}+2\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)\sin{t}=2(\sqrt{2}-1).$$ Setting $x=\sin{t}$ gives the quadratic equation $$3x^2+2\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)x-2(\sqrt{2}-1)=0.$$ Choosing the positiv root $x=\frac{2^{3/4}+\sqrt{2}-2}{3}=\sin{t}$ gives $$r=\frac{1}{1+\sin{t}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{2^{3/4}+\sqrt{2}-2}{3}}=1+\sqrt{2}-2^{\frac{3}{4}}.$$ The maximal area is hence given by $$A_{max}=\frac{r^2\pi}{2}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2}-2^{\frac{3}{4}})^2}{2}\pi\approx0.8426 \ \ a.u$$ Multiplying this with $a$ we get the desired result.

---

**Question.** Is there a way of using derivation to get the same answer?

Comment: Any thoughts or tries? As stated it just looks like you want us to do your home work.

Comment: No not really, I'm a hobby mathematican. I just like to se different solutions of problems. But posting an immediate solution would just defeat the purpose of letting others try. Or maybe there is already a thread where people post open problems for others to solve, and the guy who solves it first gives a new problem to keep the thread a live?

Comment: A good question would be to post the problem, give your solution, and ask if anyone has a different solution/nicer solution. (I am not the one who down voted)

Comment: Ok thanks, then I will post my solution soon :)

Comment: Now you have a much better question!